# vscode select first occurring string from cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to select the word[s] boundary of the next most string. I'd be okay with an extension if that's needed. Of course, this would need to be dependent on the language grammar.

For example:

```js
  co▮nst a = "a is a const";
```

Assuming the cursor is after the 'o' in const, doesn't really matter though, is there a keyboard shortcut, or a way to enable, navigating (and selecting) the next most string's content without the delimiters; `a is a const` in this example.

These are the only thing I could find, but vscode has some weird naming conventions for some settings. I also tried searching for 'navigate'.

[image]

---

#### Edit

While using SelectBy, I decided on the following for common web dev string delimiters:

```
"SelectString": {
    "forward": "(?<!\\\\)(['\"`])",
    "forwardNext": "(?<!\\\\){{1}})",
    "forwardInclude": false,
    "forwardNextInclude": false,
}

{
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
}
```

Takes escaped characters into account, but, disclaimer, if your cursor is currently in a string and you activate it, it will find a nested string, provided it's there of course.

Additionally, I decided to add `!editorHasSelection` to the when clause because otherwise it will consider the ending delimiter of a current selection, the new beginning. But that's too each their own type of thing.

Comment: You can use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by to move cursor based on regex, Just search for the different ways you can start a string, single quote, double quote, and triple variants (Python)

Comment: thanks @rioV8 tried it out and it doesn't behave the way I'm expecting, at least I couldn't get it to. It selects everything before or after the cursor postion, based on a regex. I am expecting it to 'jump' to the beginning of the string (a) *and* select it's content til the end delimiter. I guess technically you could `move` it first and then select it, but that would require 2 keyinds pressed consecutively for 1 action, would like to avoid that. Thanks though I'll keep looking for more extensions

Comment: I'll see if I can modify the extension to include this type of select, I did not catch the **select** part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v0.7.0 you can select the next string with the following settings

```
    "selectby.regexes": {
      "stringContent": {
        "forward": "('''|\"\"\"|'|\")",
        "forwardNext": "{{1}}",
        "forwardInclude": false,
        "forwardNextInclude": false
      }
    }
```

Define a keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+f10",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": ["stringContent"]
  }
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you were the author (should be disclaimed but not the end of the world). Anyways, that was fast! Thank you. The capture groups weren't necessary because lookbehinds and such but it's a very nice touch! Probably future proof too. It's perfect. Snappy, easy to set up, customizable, supports multiline. Great job and thank you. Can we use backreferences? Or is that a json/vscode limitation?

Comment: you need to find the exact same characters as the string opening (you can have " inside a ' delimited string. You can use backreferences like in any regex, you only need to escape the backscape `\\1`. There are always people that have a nifty use of configuration possibilities.

Comment: you are welcome to change my title or tags to suit your needs if you think there is something that can be done for better SEO exposure

Answer (score 2):

Using an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), you can do this fairly easily with this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                     // whatever keybinding you like
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(?<=([\"'`]))([^\"'`]*)(?=\\1)",  
    "isRegex": true,
    "restrictFind": "nextSelect"   // select the next match, other options here too
  }
}
```

If you want, you could store those keybinding options in a setting.

[image: demo of selecting the next string]

As you can see from the demo, it is **very hard** (and probably not worth the trouble) to construct the correct regex if you trigger this while within a string.  But just trigger it twice if you start within a string.